# AngularJS with PolymerJS

Tags: angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have the following code in a view

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projectNames">
<paper-material elevation="10">
    {{ project }}
</paper-material>
</div>
```

ProjectNames are listed as below.

```
$scope.projectNames = [
     'AngularJS, Java',
     'AngularJS, Java, Python',
     'Java, JavaScript, Python'
   ];
```

I am getting the below output.

[image: polymer material with angularJS]

**Why is `{{ projects }}` getting appended to the output. ??**

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rszLLrQ2R0oHbEqNTA63?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @JustinXL . I made something wrong which i am not able to find out. Let me look again and get back.